# How can I get the screen size?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I get the screen size with code, as in:

> small or
>   normal or
>   large or
>   xlarge

Thanks

EDIT: It is not the dimensions I want, I would like the thing that defines either if it is small, normal, large or xlarge, like what you have in layout folders, /res/layout-normal or /res/layout-xlarge

Comment: Do you mean get the screen dimensions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions

Comment: I did not downvote you but... this is something you could easily find out yorself by searching the web with ye favorite search engine.

Comment: I searched, all I got was how to get resolution...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) class. Here's a [nice sample](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/02/get-screen-resolution-of-android-device.html) for you.

Comment: Sorry was going to but it said please wait 4mins then I forgot